# Force on an electron at an arbitrary point inside a cylinder (electron gun)

Tags: forces, electrons, electric-fields, vector-fields

I want to simulate the path of an electron through the anode of an electron gun. I therefore need to calculate the force on the electron due to the electric field from the anode and apply that to its existing velocity. The electron can start at any arbitrary point $p$ with velocity $v$ (both vectors).

I guess that I need to integrate the force on the electron from the whole inside surface of the cylinder. I'll be doing a numerical integration.

I'm struggling to find the appropriate vector equations. I can see that $F = q\frac{V}{d}$ but all these terms are scalar not vector quantities.

Comment: I think $F=qV/d$ is the force a charged particle experiences when between two infinite parallel plates with potential difference $V$, which is not what you're trying to do. In general you will probably need to numerically solve for the potential as a function of space, compute the gradient, and then use that field to simulate particle trajectories. You might want to look into finite-element software for this.

Comment: How simple is your geometry? For extremely simple geometries, closed-form expressions for the force may exist. For anything more complicated resembling something in real life, you'll need to compute the boundary-value solution of Poisson's equation on the relevant domain.

Comment: How about if I took the point I'm interested in and, for each point on the cylinder surface, calculated the vector from one to the other. If I normalise that vector and multiply by the voltage then I'll get the field by summing all the resultant vectors for each point.

Comment: Possibly, but what do you mean when you say "calculate the vector from one to the other"? Is this a TV-screen type of thing? I don't think it's quite as simple as treating the high-voltage surfaces as if they're a uniform surface charge distribution, since they're made of metal and thus are at equipotentials. Are you at a college or university? Check to see if they offer COMSOL licenses.

Comment: Also, are you planning on building this?

Comment: I'm not a student and unfortunately I'm not a mathematician either! I'm a software developer trying to model the path of an electron through a metal cylinder. Ultimately I will build the real thing but I want some understanding of what's happening first.